# What does this command do? import re re.sub('".*?"', ' ', text)

Tags: python, regex

What does this command do?

```
import re
re.sub('".*?"', ' ', text)
```

It seems that it does not do anything and none o the texts online says anything meaningful!

Comment: It replaces any text between `""` with a space character. See [here](https://regex101.com/r/k1c2Kh/2).

Comment: It doesn't do anything because you're not assigning the result of `re.sub()` anywhere.

Comment: Please try to at least read the official Python documentation.

Answer (score 1):

It replaces text in quotation marks (and including the quotation marks) with a space.

```py
text = 'Things "in quotation marks" don\'t matter'
re.sub('".*?"', ' ', text)
```

returns

```py
"Things   don't matter"
```